# Eclipse open multiple workspaces from bat file

Tags: windows, eclipse, batch-file

My current project requieres 3 workspace open at once. This is just a little time saver. Is it possible to set the workspace as paremeter, in that case how is it done?

```
start D:\Eclipse\eclipse\eclipse.exe
exit
```

Comment: "Cheese bones"? **`;)`**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the `-data` command line switch with an argument of the workspace's location, e.g. `D:\Eclipse\eclipse\eclipse.exe -data d:\Eclipse\workspace1`.

http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm?cp=0_3_0